# Fluent nHibernate mapping problem

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have two tables, lets say shop and department.

```
ShopTable
  ShopId
  ShopName

DepartmentTable
  DepartmentId
  ShopId
  Name
  Type
```

Ok now I map shoptable to Shop class

```
   public class Shop
   {
        public virtual int ShopId {get; set;}
        public virtual string ShopName {get; set;}
        public virtual Department Toys { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Hardware { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Food { get; set; }
   }

   public class Department
   {
       public virtual int DepartmentId { get; set; }
       public virtual int ShopId { get; set; }
       public virtual string Name { get; set; }
       public virtual DepartmentType Type { get; set; }
   }
```

How do I map the toys hardware and food?

```
   public class ShopMap : ClassMap<Shop>
   {
       Id(x => x.ShopId);
       Map(x=> x.ShopName);
       // How do I map these according to the DepartmentType enum?
       Map(x=> x.Toys);
       Map(x=> x.Hardware);
       Map(x=> x.Food);
   }

   public class DepartmentMap : ClassMap<Department>
   {
       Id(x => x.DepartmentId);
       Map(x=> x.ShopId);
       Map(x=> x.Name);
       Map(x=> x.Type);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class structure you show in the question won't support what you want to do given the database table schema. There is a one-to-many relationship from the Shop class to the Department class. Here is a mapping that will work given your table structure:

```
  public class Shop
   {
        public virtual int ShopId {get; set;}
        public virtual string ShopName {get; set;}
        public virtual IList<Department> Departments { get; set; }
   }

   public class Department
   {
       public virtual int DepartmentId { get; set; }
       public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }
       public virtual string Name { get; set; }
       public virtual DepartmentType Type { get; set; }
   }
```

For a mapping of:

```
   public class ShopMap : ClassMap<Shop>
   {
       Id(x => x.ShopId);
       Map(x=> x.ShopName);

       HasMany(c => c.Departments);
   }

   public class DepartmentMap : ClassMap<Department>
   {
       Id(x => x.DepartmentId);

       References(x => x.Shop, "ShopId");

       Map(x=> x.Name);
       Map(x=> x.Type);
   }
```

Comment: Yea I know that I can have the objects as a list, but you say that it isn't possible to have them as separate objects in any way?
Would help me quite a bit, because if they are in a list I'll have to loop the list every time I access one of them.

Comment: You can't avoid searching the collection for the specific departments you want. The recommended classes will allow NHibernate to generate the correct SQL for your table structure. You could encapsulate the specific queries on the collection in either properties or methods on your class. These methods or properties would not be mapped in NHibernate so they would not affect the database operations. For example: public Department Toys { get { Departments.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DepartmentId == ToysDepartmentId); } }

Comment: It's a bit weird because with collections you can do it like this. HasMany(x => x.Departments).KeyColumn("ShopId").Where(y => y.Type == DepartmentType.Toys);

Comment: That's basically a constraint on the relationship. It seems you have a business concern to expose departments by type on your entity to the application. That is not a database mapping concern. Even if you chose this approach, I don't believe that you can use multiple HasMany clauses between the same tables and still have NHibernate generate valid SQL.